# Graph Theory Circuit vs Tour

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

There are so many different definitions that it is hard to keep them all straight. Often books choose to describe only a subset of them which leaves me wondering about the comparisons between.

Particularly I am interested in the difference between a Tour and a Circuit in Graph Theory.

What differences are there between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these terms appear in the same book, *tour* probably means that every node is visited exactly once, while *circuit* could mean that some nodes are visited exactly once but others are allowed to be omitted.